# Constant function from Any to Unit in Scala standard library

Tags: scala

I am looking for a constant function in Scala standard library with signature `Any => Unit`.

I noticed that often is used as anonymous function `_ => ()` so come with a question:

There is any particular reason to don't have a constant function in the standard Scala library?

P.S.: I still admit that maybe this function exists and I just didn't search for it enough.

Comment: You can define your own function. val y = (x: Any) => println(s"x:   $x")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider defining singleton object function which can act as constant like so

```
object constFun extends (Any => Unit) { def apply(x: Any): Unit = () }
```

We can use it in usual ways

```
List(1,2,3).foreach(constFun)
```

Answer (score 4):

`const` can be accessed using `Function.const`

```
scala> val f = Function.const(())(_: Any)
f: Any => Unit = $$Lambda$1264/445350376@234cff57
```